# Best practice on Laravel application, using 2 different auths

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a Laravel application where a user can be authenticated in 2 different ways.

1. The default eloquent user authentication
2. An API which can return a `true` or `false` if the user's credentials are valid.

I've been looking into guards and providers but still couldn't find the best practice on how to do this.

Comment: Guards and providers have nothing to do with you checking credentials against a database (or another service). Is your question about *how* to do it or how to *organize* your code?

Comment: @Mjh How I read it in the Laravel documentation is that the Provider handles the authentication.. I could be wrong here, but I also cannot find a way to handle the authentication externally in the "Laravel way"

Comment: You could use https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport, however, this will do more than just return a boolean value. Also, you are right, guards and (user) providers are what are used to authenticate a user but please don't get the provider mixed up with a service provider.

Comment: @Chris can you post a link to what you read exactly? A provider is a concept, it's a way of providing a service by hooking it into Laravel's internal constructs. It's got nothing to do with performing the work. To authenticate a user in Laravel, you pass an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` to `\Auth::login()`. That means the following: the default model (`App\User`) implements the above contract. Once the model is loaded (via Eloquent, using username + password), it's passed to `\Auth::login();` method. I can expand with the answer if this is what you're after.

Comment: @Mjh A guard in this case would be something link the `SessionGuard` and the provider would be something like the `EloquentUserProvider`. If you have a look in your `config/auth.php` you'll see that this is the terminology that is used. You are absolutely right though, this is not something that should be mixed up with a `ServiceProvider`.